# Android HttpURLConnection disconnect

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

In my activity i am calling a url using httpurl connection.
 In the case when the network strength is very low, i want to disconnect that request.

```
  How can i disconnect an httpurl connection request that is already been sent?
```

I want to cancel the request when back button is pressed.

Answer (score -1):

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
// The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

TIMEOUT IS BASICALLY FOR SLOW CONNECTIONS. After that much time your connection will get disconnected

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with cancelling the request after a button press, and it doesn't relate to `HttpURLConnection` at all.